# Integrating Layoutit into a bootstrap theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, layout

This is a very basic question but i'm having difficulty finding a laymans solution on the web.

I have the basic boostrap up and running with pages in .php.  I have created and downloaded a simple layout using layoutit.

The thing i'm having difficulty with is integrating the two together.  Layoutit exports as:

Src folder

- index.html
- css folder
- img folder
- js folder
- less folder

My bootstrap theme is set up as:

'theme name' folder

- index.php
- style.css
- 'Bootstrap' folder

  - css folder
  - img folder
  - js folder

How do i incorporate the layoutit files into my basic theme and retain the editing functionality within wordpress.org?

I'm a newb to this so any help would be gratefully received.

Dezza

Comment: I'm not sure what you need, but [try this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite what i'm after.  I understand the basic WP structure but trying to find out how to integrate layoutit's export into this.  http://www.layoutit.com/

Comment: What you want is transform a static view in a dynamic view, you could try [reading this](https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/html-wordpress/).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have a read and give it a go.